# How to get Textarea values in Razor(blazor) component, if Textarea is generated under foreach loop dynamically for more then once

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, blazor

can anyone please help to get the Textarea values from Razor component if Textarea generated under foreach loop dynamically for more then once.

I have tried with `@bind-Value and value` but still not able to get all Textareas values individually.

```
Razor component code
<EditForm Model="@userans" OnValidSubmit="@oninput">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <h3>Test </h3>


    @if (Questiontable == null)
    {

        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Questiontable[0].Questiondata)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.Question</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            **<textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="20" @bind="@userans.answers"></textarea>**
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" @onclick="btnnextclick">Next</button>
        </div>
    }
</EditForm>
```

Razor component is loading data coming from database and generating Textarea as many as database records but as soon as im updating Textarea, i need to get all values available in different Textareas.

Comment: What's the type of `userans.answer`, IMO,it should be a list and if you set it as a string, that will be the reason why you could not get all Textareas values individually.

Comment: @XingZou you're right, userans.answer is property of class, i used List now and its working,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is every single one of your textareas is binded to the same `userans.answers`

You can do something like this which I just tested out:

```
 @page  "/test-loop"

<h3>TestLoop</h3>
@foreach (var test in TestList)
{
    <div>Id: @test.Id</div>
    <textarea @bind="test.TextAreaValue">

    </textarea>
}


@* To show it's working: *@/
@foreach (var test in TestList)
{
    <div>Id: @test.Id</div>
    @test.TextAreaValue
}
<br />

@* Get The values on an event test *@
<button @onclick="ButtonClicked">
    Test
</button>
@code {

    List<TestObject> TestList = new List<TestObject>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        TestList.Add(new TestObject()
        {
            Id = 1
        });
        TestList.Add(new TestObject()
        {
            Id = 2
        });
        TestList.Add(new TestObject()
        {
            Id = 3
        });
    }

    public void ButtonClicked()
    {
        //TestList has the values of each textarea in it
    }

    public class TestObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TextAreaValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @kyle, it worked, the only issue was i was using class instead if List. now i have change class to List. Can you please explain, why it is not working with Class?

Comment: Because Required field validator  will not work in this case, correct?

Comment: If you bind them all to one class, then each input is binded to the same object. If you store them all as a list of classes, then each input is binded to an individual class.

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you want to take input based on a dynamic amount of inputs you should instantiate an array or list.
Then for every iteration in your loop where you are generating the markup add a instance to the list, then bind the input to the index value of input instance in the array.

I have not used blazor before so please don't quote me on syntax but this general idea should be what you are looking for:

```
@{
    List<string> myInputs = new List<string>();
 }
@for (int i = 0; i < Questiontable[0].Questiondata.length; i++){
    myInputs.Add(string.Empty);
    <th>
    <textarea id="TextArea" rows="2" cols="20" @bind="@myInputs[i]"></textarea>
    </th>

 }
```

Hope this helps you!